# How to help the compiler optimize my program based on the constraints of inputs?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, constraints, compiler-optimization

I have something similar to the following implemented for setting a GPIO pin in C:

```
void f(int pin) {
    bank[pin/32] = 1 << (pin%32);
}
```

Now, I know that it is undefined behavior to supply this function with a value less than 0 or greater than 63 (the registers surrounding `bank` are read as garbage), and thus this code can be treated as equivalent:

```
void f(int pin) {
    bank[pin > 31] = 1 << (pin - 32*(pin>31));
}
```

I don't know enough about my architecture to determine which one will translate to the most efficient machine code, and this is just one of many examples of functions like this across multiple platforms. But if I could somehow instruct my compiler to assume that 0 <= pin < 64, then it could theoretically choose the most efficient of the above implementations for me.

Is there a way to inform the compiler of constraints that may be beneficial during the optimization procedure?

Answer (score 2):

You could make pin a bit field struct:

```
struct Pin
{
     unsigned int pin : 6; // can hold values up to 64
};
```

Comment: Is `unsigned int` the same size on all platforms?  I assume you mean 64 bits.

Comment: It is the same size. But the bit field syntax requires you to declare the fields as unsigned into. And a 6 bit field can hold values between 0 and 64

Comment: Clever idea, but this might well produce worse code since the padding in the struct isn't necessarily initialised. If so the compiler will be obliged to emit code to mask off the unknown bits. (And `gcc` seems to do exactly that.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and easiest change is to make `pin` unsigned. This should improve the code emitted for division and modulo by constant for any reasonable compiler (because the negative case need not be handled).

Some compilers allow you to specify additional information via implementation specific machinery such as VS's `__assume`. Under what circumstances it is effective to do so is an interesting question.

Comment: I happened to stumble across gcc and clang's `__builtin_unreachable()` function that is similar to MSVC's `__assume`, as well as an article about how useful it *really* is. I'll leave a link here for anyone interested: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1096